# Filter DataFrame using groupby and head (conditionally)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to filter this dataframe using pandas `groupby` and head conditionally. This is an example `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Yes', 2], ['Yes', 4], ['Yes', 6], ['No', 8], ['No', 5],
                   ['No', 6], ['No', 3], ['Maybe', 10], ['Maybe', 2],
                   ['Maybe', 7]], columns=['A', 'B'])
```

The number of filtered rows would be variable but always should be an even number (the maximum even number of rows for every group).
This should be the result `DataFrame`:

```
  A      B
0 Yes    2
1 Yes    4
2 No     8
3 No     5
4 No     6
5 No     3
6 Maybe  10
7 Maybe  2
```

I don't know how to use `df.groupby.head()` properly. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

By using `floor`

```
df.groupby('A').B.apply(lambda x : x.iloc[:int(np.floor(len(x)/2)*2)]).reset_index().sort_values('level_1').drop('level_1',1)
Out[1458]: 
       A   B
6    Yes   2
7    Yes   4
2     No   8
3     No   5
4     No   6
5     No   3
0  Maybe  10
1  Maybe   2
```

Comment: Thank you, it works for the example. Is this solution valid in case of multiple groupby columns? I mean `df.groupby(['A', 'A1'])['B', 'B1'].apply(lambda x : ...`